# Best way to upload CSV and insert its info into database table using Django and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql

What is the best way to upload a CSV file information and then saving it into a PostgreSQL table?
If the upload is successful I will check on the database, I don't want to show the table anywhere in the templates.

Please inform if you need more info.

template where the upload will happen:

```
{% extends "product_register/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="file1">Upload a file: </label>
    <input type="file" id="file1" name="file">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg"><i class="far fa-save"></i> 
            Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="{% url 'product_list' %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block btn-lg">
                <i class="fas fa-stream"></i> Lista de Produtos
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
def category_form(request):
    """Cadastro de Categorias"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "product_register/category_form.html")
    else:
        #CSV UPLOAD HERE
        
    return render(request, "/product")
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    """Classe Categoria"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class CategoryUpload(forms.ModelForm):
    """Upload de Categorias"""
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: maybe [django-import-export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [django-import-export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and use foreign key widget  for look ups.
also there are lots of widgets with this package.